# Is this the basic git workflow?

Tags: git, github

I have been studying git for a while, but this is the first time that I am going to apply what I'm learning in a real programmer job. I only know what some of the git commands do but not what we would do with those in a real workflow, so is my vision right:

Starting:

- We will fork a repository to our GitHub
- We will clone in our local machine

Project development:

- We will create a new branch every time we need to add a new feature
- When we are sure the feature is complete and isn't broken, we merge this branch with master
- We create a pull request explaining what we are adding.

is this right?

Comment: Yes but "we merge this branch" is out of place. The merge is the culmination of the pull request. You make the pull request and, if it passes muster, it gets merged.

Comment: If you are part of a team, then it would be a good idea to discuss this with them. Some workflows depend on the project/team. For example, forking a repository then cloning, sometimes you can just clone it directly. Or, creating release branches before merging. There are many variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't merge the branch to master locally. Instead, when a feature is ready, push that branch to your remote fork, and create a pull request from it. Once it is merged there, pull the latest master to continue developing on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, except you merge it by creating a pull request.

Also see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that...

## Starting:

1. We will fork a repository to our GitHub
2. We will clone in our local machine
3. Add a remote 'upstream' toward the forked repo to be able to sync (`fetch`)

## Project development:

1. We will create a new branch every time we need to add a new feature
2. Create at least 1 commit
3. We create a pull request explaining what we are adding early in the development to gather feedback.
4. Iterate: Discuss, review, and add more commits, sync with upstream if needed (most of the time with a `rebase`) . *Do this step as many times it is needed*
5. Optional : the upstream project will probably ask you to clean your history by squashing some or all the commits  (after the final review)
6. The pull request  will be merged by the maintainer when he thinks the pr is of good quality.